# Best way to make fake path in linux?

Tags: bash, apache, docker, filesystems

Working part: I have folder with images for my website, but for local purpose, it is not necessary to show real images. I wrote php script, which serves fake image only with text of whole demanded path, script is located on root of image folder and activated for everything by .htaccess.

The other part - making thumbnails by php script is working directly in filesystem, so Apache does not affect these - and I have problem with non existing folders, files, etc. Is there some nice way to make similar fake path directly in filesystem?

I'm using docker image for this problem, so I'm able to do everything inside this image.
I'm avoiding to make changes directly in the scripts, because of temporary situation of server changing (change the path to serve over apache etc is not possible).

Thank you for your advice :).

Comment: I think that another approach "more simpler" is to create the fake images on demand instead or having them saved on a "faked" path.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a linux softlink directory:

```
ln -s file1 link1
```

Comment: Ok, it should be - create softlink for each file, but I have to do it instantly and it makes thousands of softlinked nonexisting folders and files. Is there way to do it "on demand by php"?

Comment: php could run a system command to create these softlinks?